# Trying to edit background image using jquery, interprets string wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, background

I am trying to get the background image of a div, to then apply the same image to a new div.

JS code

```
var bg = $(this).css('background-image');
bg = bg.replace('url(','').replace(')','').replace('http://SERVERIP', '');
console.log(bg);

$('.messages-container').prepend('<div class="message-overview" style="background: url(' + bg + ') no-repeat center center;-webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover; background-size: cover;">\
                                    <img class="overview-picture" src="' + $(this).children('.cloud').children('img').attr('src') + '">\
                                    <p class="overview-name">' + tempPartner + '</p>\
                                </div>');
```

Changed html

```
<div class="message-overview" style="background: url(" assets="" profiles="" popatop15="" title_picture.png")="" no-repeat="" center="" center;-webkit-background-size:="" cover;="" -moz-background-size:="" -o-background-size:="" background-size:="" cover;"="">                                        <img class="overview-picture" src="/assets/profiles/popatop15/profile_picture.png">                                        <p class="overview-name">popatop15</p>
                                </div>
```

This makes no sense for me though. As you can see, I am console logging bg, and in the log it says "/assets/profiles/popatop15/title_picture.png".

Why is bg interpret as multiple values in this case? :o

Answer (score 1):

I think this only is a quote escaping issue.
Your forged css url is not wrapped by quotes.

In your `prepend` replace this:

```
url(' + bg + ')
```

By this:

```
url(\'' + bg + '\')
```

**-----

EDIT**

It finally turns out that there is also some double quotes to be removed from `bg`.
Your `bg` is forged from a CSS `background-image` property which has these double quotes wrapping the adress between the parenthesis.

These double quotes interfere with the ones used to wrap the `style` string where `bg` is inserted.

**So,** use what I suggested before this edit **and also** change this line:

```
bg = bg.replace('url(','').replace(')','').replace('http://SERVERIP', '');
```

for this one:

```
bg = bg.replace('url("','').replace('")','').replace('http://SERVERIP', '');
```

Comment: Had that before. It then turns the html to this: <div class="message-overview" style="background: url(" "="" assets="" profiles="" popatop15="" title_picture.png"")="" no-repeat="" center="" center;-webkit-background-size:="" cover;="" -moz-background-size:="" -o-background-size:="" background-size:="" cover;"="">                                        <img class="overview-picture" src="/assets/profiles/popatop15/profile_picture.png">                                        <p class="overview-name">popatop15</p>                                    </div>

Comment: Ok... Use single quotes then... ;) You're right, I,ll edit

Comment: Hey ! Use it only around the bg var you try to insert! Not everywhere.

Comment: Reading on escaping (usefull to know... VERY usefull) : http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3470891

Comment: And WHY add a quote wrapping especialy on this var ? Because CSS expects it. Reading here : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp

Comment: Uhm.. url('\' + bg + \'') breaks it, if anything url(\'' + bg + '\') might have worked, as the backslashed ' need to be within the string. It did not though. Please be aware that I am prepending it with jquery, so everything getting added is defined in a string.

Comment: Again... Your right... I made a mistake. lolll hold on 2 sec for the edit.

Comment: I inversed the two... lol funny mistake! The first quote is escaped... Which means it will be inside the string of the prepend. The second is not, which ends the string. Then the + add the content of the variable...

Comment: I know. I did that, yet it still respons in the same way.

Comment: hew... What is the rendered html now?

Comment: I just noticed the \ after your end tags... Remove that! I don't see no use to it. I don't think it's not the problem... But Maybe ?!?

Comment: The log of the debug: <div class="message-overview" style="background: url('"/assets/profiles/popatop15/title_picture.png"') no-repeat center center;-webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover; background-size: cover;">                                <img class="overview-picture" src="/assets/profiles/popatop15/profile_picture.png">                                <p class="overview-name">popatop15</p>                            </div>

Comment: The \ escapes the linebreak. Otherwise it stops the string there.

Comment: You now have both single quote and double. : «url('"/as...ng"')» NO GOOD. Have to have only one quote set! Remove the double, since it is already wrapping the whole style string.

Comment: About the escaping linebreaks... Ok, well maybe. But I Never had to do this.

Comment: I am currently using (\'' + bg + '\'). The rest it does itself for some reason

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112978/discussion-between-louys-patrice-bessette-and-pariah).